# GID.sharedInstance().signIn() crashes app

Tags: ios, google-signin

I have read the google docs to seek for an answer, I also looked on some similar posts but none of these helped me solve my problem.
I am trying to set UIButton as the trigger for google sign in.
For some reason, it crushes.
I am of course adding the code I have written.
Thanks in advance!

I have tried everything around this issue written by StackOverflow.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }



    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

        if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]))
        {
            return true;

        }else if(url.absoluteString.contains("www.mydomain.com")){
            print("incoming url \(url.absoluteString)")

            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    // [START openurl]
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {


        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                              sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                              annotation: annotation))
        {
            return true;
        }else if(url.absoluteString.contains("www.mydomain.com")){

            print("incoming url \(url.absoluteString)")
            return true
        }

        return false;

    }






}
```

```
//
//  LogInViewController.swift
//  Flash Chat
//
//  This is the view controller where users login
// Control–Command–Space bar to get emojes

import UIKit
import Firebase
import SVProgressHUD
import GoogleSignIn

class LogInViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    //Textfields pre-linked with IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var upperView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var warningLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        roundCorners(button: loginButton)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        upperView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func roundCorners(button: UIButton) {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func signInViaGooglePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        //if any error stop and print the error
        if error != nil{
            print(error ?? "google error")
            return
        }
        print("Succses")
        //if success display the email on label
    }

    @IBAction func logInPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        if checkDetailsValidity(){
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.warningLabel.text = "Incorrect email or password"
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }
                else {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    print("Successfuly logged in!")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChat", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func checkDetailsValidity() -> Bool {
        if emailTextfield.text!.isEmpty {
            warningLabel.text = "Email is mandatory field"
            return false
        }
        else if !emailTextfield.text!.contains("@") || !emailTextfield.text!.contains("."){
            warningLabel.text = "Email is illegal"
            return false
        }
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you have tried? Maybe some links to SO posts that didn't quite work and what didn't work about them? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, first I'm despretly trying to upload my LoginViewController.. it says formatting is wrong or somthing like that..

Answer (score 1):

you must set the key of app to the delegate of GIDSingIn in the view didLoad do this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "yourappkey.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID = "yourappkey.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    roundCorners(button: loginButton)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
    upperView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

replacin *youappkey* for  your real one. then use this function to present the login view.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and this one to close the login window.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all, I want to thank you because it doesn't crash anymore!
but the methods you provided here are not the methods desired by the protocol...
what I must implement is   
 

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    }


and I dont know how to load google view.
nothing happens when I press the google button.

Comment: this method are just for presenting the singing viewcontroller in your viewcontroller you already have the singIn func

Comment: literally, nothing happens whether I have these methods or not...
this is frustrating

Comment: remove the extra methods in your appDelegate and check what you deployment target.

Comment: also print the error in you singin func perhas is retorning some error that you are missing

Comment: what extra method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197718/discussion-between-kjoe-and-avishai-yaniv).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to integrate GoogleSignIn https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

Also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmnI5c85sf0 visually helps setting up the sign in.

You might be missing the URL Schema to handle the sign in.